# Looking for a timer 20 mins on 5 mins off

Tags: power-supply

I built a solar power heater for my pool. Using 500 ft of black hose and pump. The problem I have is the water that runs through the hose is cooling it down after about 20 mins. I was curious if there is a device or something that I can plug into the outlet that I can set to run 20 mins on and off for 5 mins. Giving the hoses time to heat back up from the sun. I dont even know where to begin to look. Id rather not build one, I would rather just purchase something already that would work. So if you have any ideas I am all ears. Thanks so much

Comment: Why not run the pump 20% slower?

Comment: This is not a shopping site.  However, if you head over to eBay and use search string "cycle timer 12V", you will find something suitable.  You will have to provide a 12 Vdc power supply to run the board but the relay should control your pump just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Does it matter if the hose has time to heat up?

Isn't the sun imparting the same amount of radiant energy to the water through the hose regardless of the temperature of the hose?  Therefore you can just circulate continuously.  If you're trying to get the output temperature to be a particular value you can restrict the flow with a gate valve  on the pump output so that the time in the hose is longer

For *conducted* heating the *rate* of heat transfer is related to the *difference* in temperatures, but the amount of energy input is the same.

Answer (score 0):

How technically capable are you?

I provided a suggestion where to purchase an inexpensive 12V timer that would do what you ask but the better method is to add a bit more electronics to the system so that the pump runs when needed.

If I was doing this project, I'd start by having a temperature sensor at the hottest end of your solar heat collector.  Start the pump when the temperature reaches some high value and turn the pump off when the temperature drops too low.

Only you can figure out what temperature values are appropriate.

This method makes the system automatic.  The problem with a timer-only system is that there isn't any compensation for cool days.

With an automatic system such as I described, the pump runs only when there is sufficient heat to do some good.